# Auto Email Google Form Submissions based on Keywords in a String Cell Value

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-forms

I'm receiving a gmail from the below code, but NOT the form values that I want to be included. I'm trying have a Google Form (Sheet) send an email to me (a teacher) when a student would type an important or alarming keyword in one of the form's fields (col J).

Picture a Google form with essentially the following fields:

- A - Date/time stamp
- B - email address collection
- C - Name (short answer text)
- D - what did you learn or work on yesterday? (long answer text)
- E - How are you generally feeling today? (multiple choice)
- F - Are you tired today? (multiple choice)
- G - Are you stressed out today? (multiple choice)
- H - What have you going on today? (bunch of checkboxes)
- I - What could be "cool" or "good" about today? (long answer text)
- J - (optional) Feel free to tell me anything more (long answer text)

If the student types any alert words, like "die" or "drugs" and so on in the last column (column J), I'd like to get a gmail with a summary of all the info on the row. So far, I've set up a trigger and am only getting a gmail with a subject and message, but the message DOES NOT contain the concatenated vars values.

ALSO, the gmail's subject DOES NOT contain the concatenated studname, which would be helpful. I'm curious how you'd fix this code.
THANK YOU!!

````
function checkComments(){
var commentsRange =   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("J2");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var comments = sheet.getRange('J' + lastrow).getValue();
  
  if (comments === '.*drug.*'||'.*die.*'||'.*emotion.*'||'.*suicide.*'||) //many more root key words will be added in here in this |OR| format
{
    
// Send Alert Email.

  var timestamp = sheet.getRange('A' + lastrow).getValue();
  var studname = sheet.getRange('C' + lastrow).getValue();
  var studemail = sheet.getRange('B' + lastrow).getValue();
  var feelings= sheet.getRange('E' + lastrow).getValue();
  var tired= sheet.getRange('F' + lastrow).getValue();
  var stressed= sheet.getRange('G' + lastrow).getValue();
  var studwork = sheet.getRange('H' + lastrow).getValue();
  var cool = sheet.getRange('I' + lastrow).getValue();
  var results = timestamp + ' \n ' + studname + ' \n ' + studemail + ' \n ' + feelings + ' \n ' + tired + ' \n ' + stressed + ' \n ' + studwork + ' \n ' + cool + ' \n ' + comments;
  var emailAddress = 'my email address';
  var message = 'Alert from the daily survey!\n' + results;
  var subject = 'Daily Survey Alert from ' + studname;
    
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

To match a keyword, replace the

```
if (comments === '.*drug.*'||'.*die.*'||'.*emotion.*'||'.*suicide.*'||)
```

with

```
if(!!comments.match(/drug|die|emotion|suicide/))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed a bit your code and it seems work for me:

```
function checkComments() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // it works faster when you grab all the row at once
  var row = sheet.getRange('A'+lastRow+':J'+lastRow).getValues().flat(); 
  var comments = row[9];
  var words = ['drug','die','emotion','suicide'];

  if (words.filter(w => comments.includes(w)).length == 0) return;

  var emailAddress = 'your@mail.com';
  var subject = row[2];
  var message = row.join('\n');
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
}
```

Probably it makes sense to use RegEx to search these words in comments. But I'm not sure if you're ready to dive so deep.